# Paypal Express Steps timing basics

Tags: paypal

When using PP Express, its not clear to me until when an authorization has to be used (with DoExpressCheckoutPayment). Is this the mentioned three days time frame?

If I want to use the authorization only later (with all the risks), can I just try my token or do I need to use the Auth&Capture call as described [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-singleAuthPayment-curl-etc/) ?

Seems I did not get what additional benefit I get from DoCapture.

**Edit**: To make it more clear, I am looking for differences in timing between these workflows:

Express Checkout:

```
1. token = SetExpressCheckout(..)
2. GetExpressCheckoutDetails(token)
3. DoExpressCheckoutPayment(token,..)
```

Express Checkout w/ Auth&Capture

```
1. token = SetExpressCheckout(..)
2. GetExpressCheckoutDetails(token)
3. transactionid=DoExpressCheckoutPayment(token,PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Authorization,..)
4. DoCapture(transactionid,..)
```

Can I assume 3/29 days validity for the final Step in *both* workflows?

(I am using the first workflow successfully already, using up to three days occationally)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Token in the express checkout workflow (1/2/3) is supposed to be valid for three hours.

The workflow with Auth&Capture /1/2/3/4) is to be used if one needs to capture the money only later.

While this seems obvious now, the irritation came from the fact that the token could be used far longer than three hours in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Authorization is for merchants who have a delayed order fulfillment process and merchants have to modify the original authorization amount due to order changes (such as taxes, shipping, or item availability) that occur after the buyers place the initial order. For each authorization, PayPal honor the authorization amount for 3 days but the authorization period is 29 days. From day 4 to 29, the authorization is still valid but PayPal cannot guarantee the amount is still available to be capture.

Authorization is set during the SetExpressCheckout and then followed with DoExpressCheckout with same payment action. You can't have the payment action method passed differently using the same token. Each Express Checkout token only valid for 3 hours.Probably you wanted to try out by yourself [here](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/expresscheckout?interactive=ON&env=sandbox)?